# Accessible method for image replacement with title (title and aria-label)

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers, wcag

On my web page I have an anchor (code below), which I visually display as an image (logotype) completely hiding the text. I'd like the anchor to be:

- accessible - read properly by screen readers,
- display a tooltip when hovered by mouse (the tooltip explains the image logotype, which may not be understood by everyone).

I use the following method:

## HTML

```
<a href="http://some-institution.com"
   title="Some Institution"
   class="replace-text-with-image">Some Institution</a>
```

## CSS

```
.replace-text-with-image {
    /* Hide the text. */
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* Display the image. */
    width: <image-width>;
    height: <image-height>;
    background-image: url(<url-to-image>);
    background-size: <image-width> <image-height>;
    background-repeat: none;
}
```

The problems with the method above:

- A guy reported to me that on encountering the link his screen reader reads both the link's contents ("Some Institution") and then the link's `title` ("Some Institution" again), resulting in a "stutter".
- I read ([in this article](https://silktide.com/i-thought-title-text-improved-accessibility-i-was-wrong/)) that using `title` for accessibility is wrong and `aria-label` should be used instead.

So I tried re-factoring to use both `aria-label` and `title`:

```
<a href="http://some-institution.com"
   title="Some Institution"
   aria-label="Some Institution"
   class="replace-text-with-image">Some Institution</a>
```

Now NVDA (the screen reader I'm testing on) reads both `title` and `aria-label` attributes resulting in a stutter again.

Other possible solutions which won't work:

- When I remove the `title` attribute and leave only `aria-label` it's read fine, but I can't remove `title` attribute, as that's an explanation for the visual users that I want to have.
- I could also stay with just `title` attribute completely removing anchor's contents, but I feel having an empty anchor is not a particularly good practice, isn't it?

What's a solution for that problem?

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would really encourage you to use the simplest possible markup, which would be an anchor element wrapped around an image element, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/pLuqqh8w/

You should be using the `title` attribute of your anchor element to describe the ***intent of the link*** (i.e. where it goes), and use the `alt` attribute to describe the ***intent of your image*** (i.e. what it is). This is how the technology is designed to work. The `alt` and `title` attributes should not be same thing.

That being said, if you REALLY want to have a tooltip that isn't announced by screen readers, here's how I would recommend doing it: https://jsfiddle.net/neht6v01/

EDIT: Using the `title` attribute isn't wrong per-se, it's just not something that should be relied upon because it has very spotty support among screen-reader/browser combinations.

Comment: Probably I wasn't clear: it's not that I want a tooltip **that isn't announced by screen readers**. Actually it's the opposite - I want the tooltip to be identical to what's announced by screen readers. My problem was that `title` would give me a tooltip but not exactly accessibility, `aria-label` would give me accessibility without tooltip, while providing both  makes NVDA read both of them which results in a stutter.

Comment: You recommend using the simplest possible markup. I used <a>text</a>, while you use <a><img alt="text" /></a>. Isn't <a>text</a> the simpler one? I avoided using <a><img /></a> consciously, because I believe that all images which are pure decorations - and that image is, it's just a visual representation of a regular anchor with a text name - should not be present in the markup HTML but only in CSS

Comment: At the end of the day, the "stutter" that you're worried about isn't a big deal. As a web developer, you can't control exactly how assistive technology is going to behave. Every screen reader/browser combination will render content differently. Your role as a web developer is to follow the standards and use the web technologies as they were designed, according to the specification. This is why I said your use of a background image is overly complicated. Background images weren't designed to be used this way. They are intended for wallpaper style backgrounds.

Comment: But if you're really set on doing this the way that you've explained, I'd recommend looking into using CSS tooltips. That may get you where you need to be. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

Answer (score 0):

You should think about which ARIA role you have to give.

The `a[href]` is a link. Can it be also an image? No. So, create an image.

```
<a href="http://some-institution.com" aria-label="Some institution">
   <span class="replace-text-with-image" role="img" title="Some institution">Some institution</span>
</a>
```

This way, the screenreader will announce the `aria-label`. And the `title` will be available to mouse users.

`title` is not bad for accessibility but can be useless for screenreaders. So you should not rely only on the `title` attribute but, as you perfectly pointed out, `aria-label` is useless for non-screenreader users.

Comment: But this link is not an image - it's a regular link with a text name and that's how I'd like screen reader to interpret it. Only for visual readers I'd like the link to be displayed as an image, but only as a pure decoration. If that would be a meaningful image (not pure decoration), I'd use <img> tag inside of an anchor.

Comment: @Robert My answer relies on adding a `span` inside the `a`. It would also work replacing `role=img` with `role=presentation` (or no role at all)

Comment: (but technically an image with an alternative text is not pure decoration)

Comment: But I don't have an image with alternative text. I have a link, which I want to decorate with an image, but only for visual users. But yes, your answer should work nonetheless. I'll test it soon.